# How to test Elasticsearch index creation?

Tags: unit-testing, elasticsearch, integration-testing

I would like to write a JUnit Test using any kind of embedded Elasticsearch engine in order to test my services which should create indexes with mappings on start-up. What is the best way to do it?

Probably, it would be also enough to use ESTestCase. Unfortunately, I cannot find simple usage examples. Could anyone provide one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no embedded Elasticsearch since 5.x any more. I would use Testcontainers for this: https://github.com/dadoonet/testcontainers-java-module-elasticsearch

PS: This code will soon move to the Testcontainers repo.